# Django query efficiency

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

If I've got:

```
class Address(models.Model):
    state = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

and a large dataset, which is more efficient:

```
Address.objects.filter(state__exact='xx').filter(city__exact='somewhere').filter(street__exact='some street')
```

OR

```
Address.objects.filter(state__exact='xx', city__exact='somewhere', street__exact = 'some_street')
```

Comment: 1.  What do you mean by "efficient"?  2.  When you measured with `time it` what did you see?  3.  When you logged the SQL output (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/logging/#id1), what did you see?

Comment: 1) Well, what I'm really asking is which is better? Perhaps I mean takes the least amount of time, or possibly, the least computation. I don't know which is more important honestly. 2) What is "time it"? Googling it (or "Django time it") wasn't much help. But I don't have a large data set to test it on, I'm building a site that hopefully will though! 3) I did not log the output! I'm a total SQL newb, that seems like a good place to start... thank you.

Comment: 1.  If you can't define more efficient, we have no idea what's important to you.  "Better" doesn't mean anything either.  You must have something you're trying to optimize.  State it in the question, please.  2.  http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html.  3.  Please **update** the question with the results.

Comment: Also, neither of those queries will run.  state__exact (note two underscores not one)

Comment: @S.Lott How do I go about using timeit on a queryset? Even when I ran it in the shell and imported the models I received an error claiming I hadn't defined the global name 'Address'.

Comment: @Matt: You have to create a module which imports everything required; is part of your Django project; has a function for each query; uses `timeit` inside the module to execute the query function a few times.

Answer (score 4):

The same `QuerySet` should be constructed, so it should be the same.  You might have tiny differences because of 3 method calls instead of 1, but as far as database query time, you will see no difference.

If there is a difference, there could be a bug somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

The latter query takes roughly 1/3 of the time of the former in my test.

Using a model with 11,695 entries.

```
class TimeZip(models.Model):
    zipcode = models.SlugField(max_length=5)
    timezone = models.IntegerField(default=-5)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

and then testing:

```
Timer("TimeZip.objects.filter(state__iexact='xx')\
     .filter(city__iexact='somewhere')\
     .filter(timezone__iexact='est')",
     "from shows.models import TimeZip"
).timeit(1000)
```

resulted in a time of **1.2074651718139648** seconds, while

```
Timer("TimeZip.objects.filter(state__iexact='xx',
     city__iexact='somewhere',
     timezone__iexact='est')",
     "from shows.models import TimeZip"
).timeit(1000)
```

resulted in a time of **0.4363691806793213** seconds.

Quite a significant difference!